# Wie ist das Wort "Batterie" in die Mischbatterie gekommen?

Tags: etymology

Das Wort *Batterie* kommt laut meinen Recherchen aus dem militärischen Bereich, bei denen viele Einheiten zusammen als Batterie bezeichnet wurden. So erkärt sich mir auch u. a. der Zusammenhang mit Batterie als Energiespeicher [wie in Wiktionary erklärt](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Batterie):

> Viele Batterien waren aus mehreren nebeneinander liegenden Einheiten zusammengesetzt, um ausreichend Leistung zu erbringen. Dieses Verfahren wird bei größeren Batterien immer noch angewandt, jedoch ist der Begriff auch auf die eigentlich einzelnen Einheiten der Batterien übergegangen.

Jedoch erschließt sich mir nicht der Zusammenhang von der ursprünglich militärischen Batterie und der sogenannten [*Mischbatterie* im Sinne einer Armatur oder eines Wasserhahns](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mischbatterie).

Wie kommt es dazu?

Comment: Nun, an einer klassischen Mischbatterie sind schonmal zwei Hähne dran - das kann man im Zweifel als "mehrere nebeneinander liegende Einheiten" verstehen. Duden erklärt das Wort als "[zusammengeschaltete] Gruppe von gleichartigen technischen Vorrichtungen" - passt doch.

Comment: Ich denke, da war auch nur ein Hahn dran, oder irre ich mich da? Aber ich denke, das bezieht sich dann auf die Misch-Elemente, also auf die Ventile, die man auf- und zudrehen kann... Ja, das wäre eventuell eine Erklärung, wobei ich mich dann frage, ob bereits zwei Elemente sich dann für das Wort "Batterie" qualifizieren können. Aber das war ja vermutlich mit "das kann man im Zweifel als ... verstehen". Auf jeden Fall ein interessanter Gedanke, ja!

Comment: Ich verstehe unter "Hahn" das Ventil, an dem man dreht - Davon gibt's klassisch zwei (bin aber kein Klempner). Von daher wäre eine moderne "Einhand-Mischbatterie" tatsächlich ein Oxymoron.

Comment: Naja, eine Batterie umschreibt eine Einheit, und eine Armatur ist eine Einheit ...

Comment: Wasserhähne scheinen überhaupt extrem militärisch zu sein: "Batterie", "Kartusche", "Armatur", .... Manche haben sogar einen "Schalldämpfer"

Comment: @Lazy Ja, das könnte durchaus eine mögliche Erklärung sein.

Comment: @tofro: 'Wasserhähne scheinen überhaupt extrem militärisch zu sein: "Batterie", "Kartusche", "Armatur"' - interessanerweise alles drei Begriffe, die man heutzutage gar nicht (bzw. allenfalls nach längerer Recherche) mit Militärischem in Verbindung bringt. Gegebenenfalls wäre somit noch eine zeitliche Einordnung interessant, wann die nichtmilitärischen Bedeutungen der Begriffe sich verbreitet haben im Vergleich dazu, wann die Bestandteile von Wasserhähnen so benannt wurden.

Comment: Ich schätze _Armatur_ kommt daher, dass es so schön glänzt.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Lat. *armare* heißt *ausrüsten* - Mit Glanz und Schimmer hat das eher wenig zu tun, sondern mit *Ausrüstung*, *Ausstattung*

Comment: @tofro Ja, stimmt. Meine Assoziation war, dass die militärische Armatur metallen ist, und dass man sie putzt, sodass sie glänzt. Lat. _arma_ ist "die Waffe", wenn ich mich nicht täusche (daher auch _Armee_ und engl. _arms_). _armatur_ wäre also "die Bewaffnung".

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Das ist auch so ein Irrtum. *arma* ist in erster Linie und ursprünglich die *Ausrüstung* oder *Werkzeug* (was natürlich Waffen beinhaltet). Nur weil die Römer, die Geschreibsel hinterließen, sich in erster Linie gerne mit Waffen ausrüsteten, meint heute anscheinend jeder, dass das nur "Waffe" hieße.

Comment: @tofro: Verstehe nicht, was dagegen spricht, davon auszugehen, dass Armatur "Bewaffnung" heißt. "rüsten" und "bewaffnen" sind ja darüberhinaus auch semantisch nah.

Comment: Die Betonung liegt auf *auch*, statt *nur*. Gegen *auch* spricht nix, gegen *nur* schon.

Comment: es scheint mir nicht gänzlich unwahrscheinlich, dass sich hinter *Armatur* im gegebenen Sinne eigentlich die gesuchte *Batterie* mit verschwundenem b verbirgt (ca. \* \*arma(b)tur), und das dies irgendwann romantisch auf *arma-* umgemünzt wurde, oder sonst wie damit im Zusammenhang steht, sowie *misch-* ebenfalls umgedeutet sein kann. Mutet semitisch an.

Comment: [3 MoNaTe SpÄtEr], was ferner ganz offensichtlich von "Bad" (aus Griechisch) herrüren muss, engsprechend der Legende dass *die Russen versucht haben, die Wasserhähne mitzunehmen, weil Sie hofften, zuhause kommt dann Wasser raus* (no offence, I'm saying precisely that the butt of the joke shouldn't and doesn't matter, irregardless of attestation alas).

Answer (score 2):

Das Wort "Batterie" kommt nicht aus dem Militärischen, sondern aus dem Lateinischen: *battuere* (spätlateinisch *battere*) bedeutet "schlagen" oder "klopfen". Auf Rumänisch heißt zB. das Schlagzeug *batteria*. Das englische Wort "to bat" (abschlagen, etwa beim Baseball) kommt ebenfalls davon.

Auch im Schach wird das Wort gebraucht: eine Batterie ist die Anordnung von Figuren mit gleicher Zugart hintereinander, zB zwei Türme auf einer Linie oder Reihe oder Dame und Läufer auf einer Diagonale. Zumindest hier ist der Zusammenhang klar, weil mehrere Figuren mit gleicher Zugmöglichkeit natürlich die Schlagmöglichkeiten verstärken.

Siehe ferner Tofro's vorangegangenen Kommentar

> Nun, an einer klassischen Mischbatterie sind schonmal zwei Hähne dran - das kann man im Zweifel als "mehrere nebeneinander liegende Einheiten" verstehen. Duden erklärt das Wort als "[zusammengeschaltete] Gruppe von gleichartigen technischen Vorrichtungen" - passt doch. – *tofro* Feb 27 at 9:05

Comment: Das ist schon mal eine vielversprechende Einleitung. Aber es ist keine Antwort auf die gestellte Frage. Die lautet nämlich: »Wie ist das Wort "Batterie" in die Mischbatterie gekommen?« Ich kann in deinem bisherigen Text noch nichts über Mischbatterien finden.

Comment: Die - eigentlich offensichtliche, implizierte - Antwort ist: die Frage ist nicht zu beantworten, weil sie von falschen Voraussetzungen ausgeht. Der Begriff kommt nicht aus dem Militärischen und deshalb ist die Frage, wie genau der Bedeutungswandel von "militärisch" zu "nicht-militärisch" vonstatten ging, nicht zu beantworten.

Comment: Dass _Batterie_ auf lateinisch _battuere_ zurückgeht ist korrekt. Es kommt zwar über das Französische ins Deutsche (https://www.dwds.de/wb/Batterie). Beides aber ist kein Widerspruch dazu, dass die Bedeutung mglw. aus der Militärsprache stammt - im Gegenteil: _schlagen_ ist ja geradezu ein militärischer Begriff. Aber selbst wenn das nicht aus der Militärsprache stammen würde, ist die Frage, was _Batterie_ in _Mischbatterie_ zu suchen hat, immernoch offen. Du scheinst dich an einer Prämisse zu stören, die du für falsch hältst. Allerdings ist sie richtig. Zudem ist sie für die Frage irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

##### Militärischer Kontext

Das deutsche Wort *Batterie* wurde im 16. Jahrhundert vom französischen Wort *batterie* entlehnt. Damit haben die Franzosen eine Anordnung von mehreren nebeneinander aufgestellten gefechtsbereiten Kanonen bezeichnet. Die Kanonen hat man nebeneinander angeordnet, um die Gesamtwirkung der Waffen zu steigern. Und genau mit derselben Bedeutung wurde das Wort in den deutschen Wortschatz aufgenommen. Daher ist es korrekt, dass der Begriff seinen ersten Eintritt in die deutsche Sprache in einem militärischen Kontext vollzogen hat. Die Franzosen haben das Wort *batterie* vom Verb *battre* abgeleitet, das *schlagen* bedeutet und auf das Lateinische *battuere* (schlagen) zurückzuführen ist, das Wurzel mehrer anderer ähnlicher Wörter ist, wie schon in einer anderen Antwort erwähnt wurde.

##### Elektrische Batterie

Diese Anordnung der Kanonen war überall üblich wo man mehrere Kanonen zur Verfügung hatte, unter anderem auch in Italien, wo man ebenfalls den Begriff *batterie* für diese leistungssteigernde Anordnung mehrerer gleicher Elemente verwendet hat. Als der Italiener Alessandro Volta um ungefähr 1800 seine elektrische Säule (»Voltasche Säule«) erfunden hat, war ihm sofort klar, dass man mehrere dieser Elemente miteinander verbinden konnte, um deren Wirkung zu steigern (Serienschaltung um die Spannung zu erhöhen, Parallelschaltung zur Steigerung der Stromstärke). Das ist genau das Prinzip der Batterie, daher verwendete Volta auch genau dieses Wort für die Anordnung mehrerer elektrischer Energiespeicher. Als diese Erfindung später zur Marktreife entwickelt wurde, begleitete der italienische Begriff *Batterie* das Produkt als es in allen Ländern der Welt und in sehr vielen Sprachen Einzug hielt. Daher wurde dasselbe Wort ein zweites Mal in die deutsche Sprache importiert, allerdings mit einer anderen Bedeutung und aus einer anderen Sprache. Weil bei der elektrischen Batterie aber im Vordergrund stand, das sie elektrische Energie speichern kann, und man für das einzelne Element eigentlich gar keinen Namen hatte (das italienische Wort *colonna,* das Volta verwendet hat, schaffte es nicht die Sprachgrenzen zu überschreiten), bezeichnet man diese elektrischen Energiespeicher selbst dann als *Batterien,* wenn sie einzeln verwendet werden.

##### Mischbatterie

Das Wort *Mischbatterie* besteht aus zwei Teilen: Den ersten Teil muss man eigentlich nicht erklären. Es ist der Wortstamm des Verbs *mischen,* und dieser Teil bestimmt näher, wozu der zweite Teil da ist.

Wenn man sich so eine Mischbatterie anschaut, erkennt man recht gut, dass hier zwei gleiche Elemente (nämlich zwei Wasserhähne) nebeneinander angeordnet sind, um aus dieser Anordnung einen Vorteil zu ziehen, den es nicht gäbe, wenn man zwei getrennte Wasserhähne hätte: Man kann heißes und kaltes Wasser mischen. Man hat also eine Batterie, die aus mehreren (nämlich genau zwei) Wasserhähnen besteht.

[image]

Aus der abgebildeten Bauform entwickelte sich in Lauf der Zeit der Einhandmischer oder Einhebelmischer, dem man äußerlich nicht mehr ansieht, dass er die Funktion von zwei Wasserhähnen in sich vereint. Trotzdem wird auch der Einhebelmischer oft auch als Mischbatterie bezeichnet (ähnlich wie die einzelne elektrische Batterie, siehe oben).

Comment: Ich glaube, dass der italienische Begriff für die Batterie _batteria_ ist. Vielleicht ein Typo?

Comment: Das hört sich alles sehr plausibel an. Die Antwort hört sich außerdem so an, als gäbe es hierzu Quellen. Da würde ich auch sehr gerne mal reinschauen. Ich störe mich zudem etwas daran, dass sich bereits zwei Elemente als Batterie qualifizieren sollen, aber das kann im Zweifelsfalls auch nur heißen, dass sich Analogie gegenüber Kreativität durchgesetzt hat (vielleicht ähnlich zu colonna vs. batteria).